# What is the correct way for me to access a public member of class A in class B when class B is a member of class A in C++?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, function-pointers

In the below example I want to be able to access vector `cList` in class `B` in the function `ShareData`. How do I do that?

I have written a sample code. It fails to compile (Error message: B has no constructors). Even if it did, does the line `cObj = new B(*this);` introduce any circular dependency?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>

class B;

class A
{
public:
    B* cObj;
    std::vector<B*> cList;
    A()
    {
        cObj = new B(*this);
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    B(A& aObj) : aObjLocal(aObj) {};
    void ShareData(int result)
    {
        for (auto& iterator : aObjLocal.cList)
        {
            (*iterator).ShareData(result);
        }
    }
private:
    A& aObjLocal;
};


void main()
{
    A aMain;
    B bMain(aMain);
    bMain.ShareData(10);
}
```

Thanks in advance for sharing the knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
    cObj = new B(*this);
```

does not work in `A`'s constructor since the definition of `B` is not visible at that line. Move the implementation of `A`'s constructor after `B` has been defined.

```
class A { ... };

class B { ... };

inline A::A()
{
    cObj = new B(*this);
}
```

Comment: Doing so results in error: "'A::A': cannot define a compiler-generated special member function (must be declared in the class first)"

Comment: @JayHawk, you have to declare the constructor in the class. `A();`. You just can't define it.

Comment: Great! Thank you.

Comment: Is there any risk if the header file and the implementation of the methods, including the constructors are in separate files?

Comment: @JayHawk, are you talking about "separate .h files" or "separatre .h files and .cpp files"?

Comment: I am talking about the case where class A and class B, including their members  is declared in one header file and the implementation of their methods are in another cpp file. Does ir matter where the constructor A:A() is present (header or cpp file)? Thanks!

Comment: @JayHawk, IMO, it is preferable to put the implementation of the constructor in a .cpp file. Just make sure to remove the `inline` qualifier.

Comment: Thanks! So there is no risk of circular dependency?

Comment: @JayHawk, circular dependency is easily avoided by understanding when forward declaration is enough and when it is not. Use of a .cpp file to implement the member functions is certainly helpful. You might find a related post interesting: [When can I use a forward declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration)

Answer (score 2):

When you are using forward declarations, you need to make sure that any usage of the forward-declared type which needs full type happens after the type becomes fully defined.

In your case, it means that your code should like following:

```
class B;

class A
{
public:
    B* cObj;
    std::vector<B*> cList;
    A();
};

class B {
   ...
};

inline A::A()
{
    cObj = new B(*this);
}
```

Also, while doing so, you certainly would want to get rid of owning `B*`, and instead use `std::unique_ptr` there.

Answer (score 1):

`cObj = new B(*this);`
You cann use B here since it's not yet defined.
Put this under the definition of B:

```
A::A()
{
    cObj = new B(*this);
}
```

and remove the inline definition.